# Solve the nonlinear equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

Suppose that $f:E\to F$(between Banach spaces), is of the form 
$$f(x)=f(0)+D(x)+N(x).$$
Here $D$ is a linear term, whose kernel is of finite dimension, and admits a right inverse $G$, i.e. $D(G)(\cdot)=Id_F$. The nonlinear term $N(x)$ satisfies that 
$$\|G(N(x))-G(N(y))\|\leq C(\|x\|+\|y\|)\|x-y\|$$

for some constant $C>0$ and $x,y$ in a small neighborhood $B_{\epsilon(C)}(0)$.

**Q**: How to show that there is a unique zero point $x_0$ of $f$, i.e. $f(x_0)=0$,  in $B_\epsilon(0)\cap G(F)$, with the initial condition $\|G(f(0))\|\leq\epsilon/2$?

Comment: What do you mean by a "zero point" of $f$?  A fixed point, that is, $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = x_0$?  No, that can't be right since $f: E \to F$; so then what?  Cheers!